# Unpredictable behavior when trying to read x86 EFLAGS register

Tags: c++, c, x86, intrinsics

I am experiencing unpredictable behavior when trying to read the x86 EFLAGS register in order to catch for integer operation overflow.

The function where the problem occurs is the following:

```
inline int64_t multiply(const int64_t op1, const int64_t op2, bool& overflow)
{
    int64_t result = op1 * op2;
    overflow = (0 != (__readeflags() & 0x801));
    return result;
}
```

When compiled for x64/Debug target, the function behaves as expected, ie: it computes the integer multiplication of operands `op1` and `op2`, then set the `overflow` boolean to `true` if the operation overflowed or `false` otherwise.

However, when compiled for x64/Release target, the function behaves in an unpredictable manner regarding the `overflow` boolean, which is randomly set to either `true` or `false` whether the multiplication overflows or not.

I can fix the issue by adding the `volatile` qualifier to `op1` declaration in function prototype, ie:

```
inline int64_t multiply(volatile const int64_t op1, const int64_t op2, bool& overflow)
{ ... }
```

Can someone explain me why I get this random behavior in x64/Release and if there is another way than making op1 `op1` `volatile` to fix this issue ?

PS: compiled with MS **vc14**, using instrinsic `__readeflags()` declared in `intrin.h` header; I guess the same intrinsic exists for **gcc**, declared in `x86intrin.h`.

---

EDIT: Added assembly code:

Code generated for the inline function `multiply()`, when the `volatile` qualifier is specified, is the following:

```
; File int_overflow.h
; Line 71
    imul    rsi, rdx
; Line 72
    pushfq
    pop rax
    test    rax, 2049               ; 00000801H
; File test_int_overflow.cpp
; Line 109
    mov rax, rdx
; File int_overflow.h
; Line 72
    setne   r8b
```

in the above assembly, the operands multiplication (`imul rsi, rdx`) happens prior to the test of the EFLAGS register (`test rax, 2049`), as expected.

Whereas, code generated for the inline function `multiply()`, when the `volatile` qualifier IS NOT SPECIFIED, is the following:

```
; File int_overflow.h
; Line 72
    pushfq
    pop rax
    test    rax, 2049               ; 00000801H
    mov rsi, rcx
; File test_int_overflow.cpp
; Line 109
    mov rax, rdx
    mov r12, rdx
; File int_overflow.h
; Line 72
    setne   r8b
; File test_int_overflow.cpp
; Line 103
    mov r13, rcx
; File int_overflow.h
; Line 71
    imul    rsi, rdx
```

in the above assembly, the operands multiplication (`imul rsi, rdx`) is postponed far after the test of the EFLAGS register (`test rax, 2049`); this is therefore the reason why the test has no correlation with the multiplication status.

I assume this is the result of a compiler optimization. So, my question is now:

**Is there a safe way to force compiler to place the multiplication before the test of the EFLAGS register ?**

Comment: Please **edit** your post with the assembly language generated by the compiler for your function.  The truth is in the assembly language.

Comment: IMO, searching for a "fix" will be in vain.  That `volatile` helped is no guarantee that future compilations will set the overflow flag as desired.  IMO 2 choices:  1) Use assembly for the multiplication and overflow flag detection.  2) Prevent overflow by other portable detection means.

Comment: @Thomas: done; see my edit.

Comment: This is futile.  You can't stop the compiler from optimizing your code in a way that clobbers the flags after the operation you want to check, but before the `__readflags()`.  You need a `checked_multiply` intrinsic or something.

Comment: Rust takes an interesting approach here: the primitive integer types have methods like [`i32.checked_mul(i32)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_mul), returning a type which can be either no-result or a number.  There's also saturating_mul, wrapping_mul, etc.  (Wrapping with normal `*` is an error.  So everywhere you intentionally want overflow / wrapping to happen the 2's complement or unsigned binary way (or to detect and handle it), you tell the compiler about it with one of those methods.  Debug builds will catch unintentionally wrapping when it happens.)